# Should this question on autofocus speed be reopened?

Tags: discussion

This question:
[Why is DSLR autofocus much faster than Mirrorless autofocus?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59901/why-is-dslr-autofocus-much-faster-than-mirrorless-autofocus)

Was marked as a duplicate of both:

- [Why are mirrorless cameras much slower than DSLRs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43265/why-are-mirrorless-cameras-much-slower-than-dslrs)
- [Why is it harder to focus using LiveView?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52932/why-is-it-harder-to-focus-using-liveview)

In the comments another user pointed out that this could be a duplicate as well:

- [What is the practical difference between phase-detect and contrast-based autofocus?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20474/1943)

Comment: Robo-voting is becoming an issue I'm starting to think.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**; the question should be reopened.

I read each of the questions noted as duplicates and also quite a few more on this topic(linked in my [answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/59902/4892) to the question) and I do not believe any of them are duplicates. I agree that a basic understanding of phase detect AF and contrast detect AF is important to have, but all of the existing questions do not specifically answer the question *Why is DSLR autofocus much faster than Mirrorless autofocus?*.

I answered the question [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/59902/4892) by explaining that Mirrorless technology has transitioned somewhat from CD AF to PD AF and that is why some confusion on the topic exists. Only having questions that point out Live View comparisons to DSLRs, or that are based on CD AF assumptions are not complete in answering the question at hand.

Breakdown of why each question isn't a duplicate:

[Why are mirrorless cameras much slower than DSLRs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43265/why-are-mirrorless-cameras-much-slower-than-dslrs)

- This isn't a duplicate because the question wants to know "shot to shot" time including all functions and not just AF. Because of this the answers do not go into specifics of AF systems across mirrorless options

[Why is it harder to focus using LiveView?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52932/why-is-it-harder-to-focus-using-liveview)

- This isn't a duplicate because the question is about DSLRs using Live View(CDAF) vs DSLRs using standard shooting modes(PDAF). It doesn't consider what is possible with mirrorless cameras.

[What is the practical difference between phase-detect and contrast-based autofocus?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20474/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-phase-detect-and-contrast-based-autofoc)

- This is a good primer to understand PDAF vs CDAF but does not if a user doesn't know how that relates to mirrorless cameras and their AF systems it isn't much help. It supports this question but does not answer it.